# eth.sign vs eth.accounts.sign create different sign

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

When I sign a string with the web3.eth.sign() method and web3.eth.accounts.sign() method. The result value of the two signatures is different. I don't know why these two results are different.

I'm using the latest web3.js. And the private key is from metamask.

This is my code

```
await ethereum.enable();
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
let msg = "sign this message"
let prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + msg.length
let msgHash1 = web3.utils.sha3(prefix+msg)

let sig1 = await web3.eth.sign(msgHash1, accounts[0]);
let privateKey = "0xcfb51f3737044cb4bfb49cbb10ae67d79ee81523d7065e95972cc23ed914e95e"
let sigObj = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(msgHash1, privateKey)
let sig2 = sigObj.signature;

console.log(sig1)
console.log(sig2)
```

And this is result.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that one method adds message prefix, another does not. You can verify this by walking through the relevant source code with step-by-step debugger.

Answer (score 4):

The [source code](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/4615f2d35c455bd81cb04f0ab8d8d2c0b140e33a/packages/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js#L312)  shows that the difference is that `web3.eth.accounts.sign` prefixes and hashes the message before signing it.

In your example pass in `msg` instead of `msgHash` to `eth.accounts.sign`:

So this signature:

```
const msg = 'hello world'
const { signature } = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(msg, privateKey)
```

will produce the same signature as `eth.sign` with hashed message:

```
const msg = 'hello world'
const msgHash = web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage(msg)
const signature = await web3.eth.sign(accounts[0], msgHash)
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is this is by design (for the best of my understanding), to prevent interpretation of a signed Ethereum transaction as other data (for example a meta transaction, verified by a smart contract logic).

More relevant details:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35425/web3-js-eth-sign-vs-eth-accounts-sign-producing-different-signatures

Answer (score 1):

`web3.eth.sign` and  `web3.eth.accounts.sign` generate the same signature in web3.js v1.3.4 .

Correct me if I am wrong, It seems `web3.eth.sign` calls `web3.eth.accounts.sign` under the hood, [here](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1ed3c68b5e99e1b5e893068ff0b2d1c86a98d1c1/packages/web3-core-method/src/index.js#L753)